# Include path being ignored

Tags: php, path, include

I'm not understanding what's going on here. I have the following:

```
set_include_path(
    get_include_path()
    .PATH_SEPARATOR.'/home/mike/www/Zend/library/'
);
```

Which appears to set the value correctly:

```
var_dump(get_include_path());
// string(61) ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/home/mike/www/Zend/library/"
```

This *should* work, however it produces `Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' not found`:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
```

But if I use the full path it works fine:

```
require_once '/home/mike/www/Zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
```

Any ideas why is it not using the include path in this case?

Comment: Does it work when using require() ? `require 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';`

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara I don't see how that's any different, but no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [include manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, **which will emit a fatal error.**

I then noticed that the script did not emit a fatal error during the `require` but instead it was on the next line that was causing the error:

```
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader($config);
```

Therefore the `require` line was including *something*, just that that something didn't contain the `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader` class.

I then whipped up this little script to see where it was coming from:

```
$include_paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
foreach ($include_paths as $path) {
    $file = 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
    echo $path .'/'. $file;
    echo '...';
    echo (file_exists($path . '/'. $file)) ? '<b>exists</b>' : 'doesnt exist';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

This is the result:

```
./Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php...doesnt exist
/usr/share/php/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php...exists
/usr/share/pear/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php...doesnt exist
/home/mike/www/Zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php...exists
```

So it turns out I had two files that *both* matched what I was trying to include. When I open `/usr/share/php/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php` I can see it instead uses the class `Zend_Loader_StandardAutoloader` with no namespace. This is from Zend framework 1.12.9 but my app is using version 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

From [Include documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing.

If you use `Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php` then it is assumed that file path is given so it used this path which of course does not point to correct directory. If you use `StandardAutoloader.php`, then it used [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) to find this.

Comment: Actually I was doing it correctly. As you can see I set the include path to include the Zend location. However see my answer for what was really going on.